# Windows microservice created from .net core using does not write logs to path

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, windows-services, serilog-sinks-file, serilog-aspnetcore

Windows microservice created from .net core using does not write logs to path

I have created a windows service from c# .net core which uses Serilog.Sinks.Async.File in appsettings.json as below

```
"Serilog": {
"Using": [
"Serilog.Sinks.Async"
],
"WriteTo": [
{
"Name": "Async",
"Args": {
"configure": [
{
"Name": "File",
"Args": {
"restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
"path": "%PROGRAMDATA%/logs/file.log",
"rollingInterval": "Day",
"formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact"
}
}
]
}
},
```

The above config is just a snippet from appsettings.json but it also includes other standard parameters set in it.

Please let me know if a windows service running as local system can write logs into %PROGRAMDATA% path configured through appsettings.json. The same log file works if it configured as part of the service in Program.cs

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
.Enrich.FromLogContext()
.Destructure.UsingAttributes()
.WriteTo.Async(a =>
a.File(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%PROGRAMDATA%\logs\file.log"))
.WriteTo.Console()
.CreateBootstrapLogger()
```

Answer (score 0):

This logging works.
package `Serilog.AspNetCore`
`Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices`

```
var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
builder.UseSerilog((hostingContext, services, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
                        .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration));
builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        services.AddWindowsService();
    });

var host =builder.Build();
host.Run();
```

```
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "%PROGRAMDATA%/Logs/log.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information"
        }
      },
```

Test
[image]